# JSP doesn't pick up bootstrap css (IDEA + Tomcat)

Tags: html, css, jsp, intellij-idea, tomcat6

Here is the thing: I'm creating some html file w/ bootstrap css in IntellijIDEA (code below). Open it in browser and all work correctly.

Copy that code to .jsp file, start Tomcat server and css's doesn't work.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Money Transfer</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

</head>

<body>
<form action="submit" method="get">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-4">
<h2 class="form-signing-heading">Money Transfer Form</h2></div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-3"><label>Sender</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><select name="sender" class="form-control">
                    <option value="John Doe">John Doe</option>
                    <option value="Mr.Smith">Mr.Smith</option>
                    <option value="ScratchCard">ScratchCard</option>
            </select></div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-3"><label>Receiver</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><select name="receiver" class="form-control">
                    <option value="jane Doe">Jane Doe</option>
                    <option value="Mrs.Smith">Mrs.Smith</option>
                    <option value="System">System</option>
            </select></div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-3"><label>Amount</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="input-group">
        <input type="amount" class="form-control" placeholder="Amount" name="amount">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-5">
                <button type="send" class="btn btn-success">Send</button>
                <button type="cancel" class="btn btn-link">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</form>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there's is a problem with relative paths. Relative path for jsp and relative path for html files are different. Upon viewing your jsp page, view source code in your browser and try to open these css files. You will get an error message.

I do not know your project files/folders structure, but I recommend to use servlet context path in your jsp file to calculate the correct path to your css files.

Use `request.getContextPath()` to get the context path in your jsp file and compose the full path to your css/javascript files using this expression.

If `bootstrap` folder is located at the root of your web-application folder, then use this construction:

```
<link href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```